# Function not accessible in Python - Error: global name is not defined

Tags: python

I'm new to Python programming and I'm stuck with the following error:

```
form="""
    <form method="post">
    What is your birthday?
    <br>

    <label> Month
        <input type="text" name="month">
    </label

    <label> Day
        <input type="text" name="day">
    </label>

    <label> Year
        <input type="text" name="year">
    </label>

    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)

def valid_day(day):
        if day and day.isdigit():
            day = int(day)
            if day > 0 and day <= 31:
                return day

def valid_year(year):
        if year and year.isdigit():
            year = int(year)
            if year > 1899 and year < 2021:
                return year
def post(self):
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))
```

I'm told that global name 'valid_day' is not defined. Can anybody tell me where is the fault? I think I defined the function valid_day / valid_year above so it should be accessible, or not?

Comment: Are some of these functions in a class or something? Is the indentation you're showing us here exactly what you have in your script? Are you using python 2 or 3 (matters because the two handle mixed whitespacing differently)

Comment: Where did you define these functions?  Are they in a class?  As shown, if this is in the top-level of a file, the valid_day and valid_year functions are defined and can be accessed.  If this is in a class, then that is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears by your use of `self` as a parameter to the `post` function that this code is inside a class.

In that case, you need to use `self` to access the methods. (Normally your assumption about scoping and defining functions above the call would be correct.)

Rewrite your post function as follows:

```
def post(self):
    user_day = self.valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
    user_year = self.valid_year(self.request.get('year'))
```

Comment: And `valid_day`/`valid_year` probably want `@static_method` decorators in that case.

Comment: Err, yes, I was assuming they're also inside the class, in which case they should also use `self` as the first parameter, which they currently don't. Probably adding that is better unless there's some compelling reason they shouldn't be a part of the same class.

Comment: I changed it that way but then I get an error that my function gets 2 arguments instead of one. I edited the Code in my question.

Comment: @rikojir Yes that's due to the discussion we were just having above. You need to rewrite the definition of `valid_day` and `valid_year` to also have `self` as a parameter. So `def valid_day(day)` becomes `def valid_day(self, day)` and likewise for `valid_year`.

Comment: @rikojir Make sure you understand the basics of class design and why `self` is necessary in Python. [This](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) seems to be a good discussion just at a glance. (Maybe someone else can suggest something better.)

Comment: Okay, your solution works, but I still don't understand, why. Changing the call of the function to include the `self`. as a prefix makes sense to me, but why does it work when i add `self` as a parameter to the functions, too? The call you wrote in your answer with `self.valid_day(self.request.get('day'))` only has one parameter, or am I wrong?

Comment: @rikojir It's because you're inside a class. Python passes `self` (meaning an instance of the class, which is only conventionally called `self`) automatically when you call the methods so you only have to write it once when the method is defined.

Comment: Ah, okay. Now all that makes a lot more sense to me. Thanks for your help!